# Stripe SDK won't let me build - "Signing for 'StripeCore' requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor"

Tags: ios, xcode, stripe-payments

Here is what I'm seeing in errors when trying to build:

[image]

It's saying I need to select a team in Signing & Capabilities. But I've already done that multiple times as you can see in this shot:

[image]

Why is it complaining about this?

I am running Xcode beta version 13.3 beta 2. I wonder if that's to do with this.

Answer (score 9):

I've got the same issue when change to build with Xcode 14.

A path on `Podfile` below should help me resolved the issue.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8891#issuecomment-1201465446

Comment: How amazing it is to develop on iOS, you upgrade and the build doesn't work any more! Thanks for the tip, though. For those wondering the snippet has to go in the Podfile itself.

Answer (score 5):

I was just having the same problem with Xcode 14 beta 3 and solved it by going into the Pods folder and finding the offending pod and manually setting the team. See the screenshot below. Hope this helps someone!

[image: Screenshot of Pod folder in Xcode with "Team" field set to "None"]

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any signing errors with the latest Stripe iOS SDK on Xcode 13.2.1 Public Release.

- I’d try logging out of your developer account and logging back in.
  Then clean the build folder and run a fresh build just to rule out
  caching or configuration issues.
- I’d also try building the app using a previous non-beta (public)
  version of Xcode to confirm that this may be related to the beta
  version of Xcode.

Seems like there’s an open issue [1] on CocoaPods GitHub repo with similar errors. There’s a workaround suggested in one of the comments that you can try and see if that resolves the errors.

[1] https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8891

Comment: Yea, I downgraded to Xcode 13.0 and it works again. I'll stick with this for now and see if I can fix it on later versions later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Select Pods in Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NSRL.png), then search **Development Team**, and select your **Team name**, it will work!